# React Native Navigation: Remove Scroll Bar on Web

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Does anybody know how to remove this scroll bar?
The code below does not help.
I am using React Native Navigation v6

```js
<DrawerContentScrollView
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
>

</DrawerContentScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: try using ScrollView instead

Comment: Nope, doesn't help.
Seems like it's something outside

Comment: i think it's not working because of the width you got there, is the menu on the left comming from navigation drawer ??

Comment: I think so, so it's happeing actually only if I use 
screenOptions={{
      drawerType: 'slide' or 'back',
    }}

Comment: try to add this to your drawer View  `scrollEnabled={false}`

Comment: No this doesn't help either, but I have found solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Native-Base V3.2.2 in my project
So the answer was just to add
overflow: "hidden"
to the root view